# Picasso view cannot be converted to Context inside DataAdapter

Tags: java, android, json, picasso

I have my application created and it is connecting to a JSON file on my server to get information on users then set it onto the card row. This is all working fine but I cannot get Picasso to work with it unless I place it within my public ViewHolder(View view) method but then I cannot access the array. Is there any way to fix this? I am getting the error

> Error:(55, 22) error: incompatible types: DataAdapter.ViewHolder
>   cannot be converted to Context

The code is posted below. Thanks.

```
package com.example.curtisboylan.myapplication;

/**
 * Created by curtisboylan on 02/02/2017.
 */
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class DataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DataAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<String> username;
    private ArrayList<String> userid;
    private ArrayList<String> location;
    private ArrayList<String> reviewscore;
    private ArrayList<String> price;
    private ArrayList<String> url;


    public DataAdapter(ArrayList<String> username, ArrayList<String> userid, ArrayList<String> location, ArrayList<String> reviewscore, ArrayList<String> price, ArrayList<String> url) {
        this.username = username;
        this.userid = userid;
        this.location = location;
        this.reviewscore = reviewscore;
        this.price = price;
        this.url = url;

    }

    @Override
    public DataAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_row, viewGroup, false);

        return new ViewHolder(view);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(DataAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
        final String item = userid.get(i);
        final String usernamepass = username.get(i);
        viewHolder.usernametext.setText(username.get(i));
        viewHolder.reviewscoretext.setText(reviewscore.get(i));
        viewHolder.pricetext.setText("€" + price.get(i) +"/hr");
        viewHolder.locationtext.setText(location.get(i));
      //"https://cms-assets.tutsplus.com/uploads/users/21/posts/19431/featured_image/CodeFeature.jpg";

        Picasso.with(viewHolder)
                .load(url.get(i))
                .into(viewHolder.profileimg);






        viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "User ID: " + item, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                Intent intent=new Intent(view.getContext(),TechnicianProfile.class);
                intent.putExtra("username", usernamepass);
                intent.putExtra("userid", item);
                view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return username.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        private TextView usernametext;
        private TextView pricetext;
        private TextView locationtext;
        private TextView reviewscoretext;
        private ImageView profileimg;

               public ViewHolder(View view) {
                       super(view);

                   usernametext = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView4);
                   pricetext = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.price);
                   locationtext = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.location);
                   reviewscoretext = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.reviewscore);
                   profileimg = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.userpic);

                    }
            }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should pass **[Context](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html)**

**new DataAdapter(..,..,CurrentActivity.this)** // Passing Context

```
     Context context;//Global 
     public DataAdapter(ArrayList<String> username, ArrayList<String> userid, ArrayList<String> location, ArrayList<String> reviewscore, ArrayList<String> price, ArrayList<String> url,Context context) {

       this.context = context;

        }
```

Now

```
 Picasso.with(context)
```

Comment: No need to pass a Context via constructor, as long as ViewHolder is aware of it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give a [`Context`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html) to [`Picasso`](https://github.com/square/picasso). Change to

```
Picasso.with(viewHolder.itemView.getContext())
        ...
```

But this is error prone, you'd better give an [application context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19615972/application-context-what-is-this) in order to evade from leakages.

Answer (score 0):

Picasso need's a Context object

```
Picasso.with(context).load("http://url/image.png").into(imageView);
```

What you can do is pass a Context object through the constructor of your adapter :

```
Context context;
public DataAdapter(Context context, ..) {
     this.context = context;
     ...
}
```

and finally pass that context object from your activity that calls the adapter :

```
adapter = DataAdapter(getContext(), ...);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Activity** has its own **Context**. But **Adapter** doesn't. So you need to pass the context from Activity to the Adapter using the constructor and you have to pass that context to the Picasso loader like this.

`Picasso.with(context)
                .load(url.get(i))
                .into(viewHolder.profileimg);`

Replace **viewHolder** to the **context** which you are getting through the constructor.